# Error en formulario con php, submit via ajax y html

Tags: php, html, ajax

Tengo un inconveniente con una template comprada a la cual no puedo hacerle funcionar su formulario, en el resto de mis paginas webs utilizo siempre "formspree.io" sin problemas, pero en este caso el formulario esta vinculado con PHP y AJAX, no solo HTML.

Adjunto el código de cómo está actualmente, arroja los siguientes errores:

> Warning: Undefined variable $message in /www/--------/------.com.ar/public/inc/sendEmail.php on line 31
>
> Warning: Undefined variable $error in /www/--------/------.com.ar/public/inc/sendEmail.php on line 47

El codigo es el siguiente:

HTML FORM:

```
<h3 class="h6">Send Us A Message</h3>

            <form name="contactForm" id="contactForm" method="post" action="https://formspree.io/f/ejemplo" novalidate="novalidate">
                <fieldset>

                <div class="form-field">
                    <input name="contactName" type="text" id="contactName" placeholder="Your Name" value="" minlength="2" required="" aria-required="true" class="full-width">
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    <input name="contactEmail" type="email" id="contactEmail" placeholder="Your Email" value="" required="" aria-required="true" class="full-width">
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    <input name="contactSubject" type="text" id="contactSubject" placeholder="Subject" value="" class="full-width">
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    <textarea name="contactMessage" id="contactMessage" placeholder="Your Message" rows="10" cols="50" required="" aria-required="true" class="full-width"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    <button class="full-width btn--primary">Submit</button>
                    <div class="submit-loader">
                        <div class="text-loader">Sending...</div>
                        <div class="s-loader">
                            <div class="bounce1"></div>
                            <div class="bounce2"></div>
                            <div class="bounce3"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

CODIGO JS/AJAX:

```
var clContactForm = function() {
    
    /* local validation */
    $('#contactForm').validate({
    
        /* submit via ajax */
        submitHandler: function(form) {

            var sLoader = $('.submit-loader');

            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "inc/sendEmail.php",
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                beforeSend: function() { 

                    sLoader.slideDown("slow");

                },
                success: function(msg) {

                    // Message was sent
                    if (msg == 'OK') {
                        sLoader.slideUp("slow"); 
                        $('.message-warning').fadeOut();
                        $('#contactForm').fadeOut();
                        $('.message-success').fadeIn();
                    }
                    // There was an error
                    else {
                        sLoader.slideUp("slow"); 
                        $('.message-warning').html(msg);
                        $('.message-warning').slideDown("slow");
                    }

                },
                error: function() {

                    sLoader.slideUp("slow"); 
                    $('.message-warning').html("Something went wrong. Please try again.");
                    $('.message-warning').slideDown("slow");

                }

            });
        }

    });
};
```

PHP:

```
<?php


$siteOwnersEmail = 'hola-------@gmail.com';


if($_POST) {

    $name = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactName']));
    $email = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactEmail']));
    $subject = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactSubject']));
    $contact_message = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactMessage']));

    // Check Name
    if (strlen($name) < 2) {
        $error['name'] = "Please enter your name.";
    }
    // Check Email
    if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9&\'\.\-_\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z0-9\-]+\.)*+[a-z]{2}/is', $email)) {
        $error['email'] = "Please enter a valid email address.";
    }
    // Check Message
    if (strlen($contact_message) < 15) {
        $error['message'] = "Please enter your message. It should have at least 15 characters.";
    }
    // Subject
    if ($subject == '') { $subject = "Contact Form Submission"; }


    // Set Message
    $message .= "Email from: " . $name . "<br />";
    $message .= "Email address: " . $email . "<br />";
    $message .= "Message: <br />";
    $message .= $contact_message;
    $message .= "<br /> ----- <br /> This email was sent from your site's contact form. <br />";

    // Set From: header
    $from =  $name . " <" . $email . ">";

    // Email Headers
    $headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $email . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";


    if (!$error) {

        ini_set("sendmail_from", $siteOwnersEmail); // for windows server
        $mail = mail($siteOwnersEmail, $subject, $message, $headers);

        if ($mail) { echo "OK"; }
        else { echo "Something went wrong. Please try again."; }
        
    } # end if - no validation error

    else {

        $response = (isset($error['name'])) ? $error['name'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
        $response .= (isset($error['email'])) ? $error['email'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
        $response .= (isset($error['message'])) ? $error['message'] . "<br />" : null;
        
        echo $response;

    } # end if - there was a validation error

}

?>
```

Consola JS:

```
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ var clContactForm = function() {
+ ~~~
La palabra clave 'var' no se admite en esta versión del idioma.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 30
+ var clContactForm = function() {
+                              ~
Se esperaba una expresión después de '('.
En línea: 9 Carácter: 17
+                 var sLoader = $('.submit-loader');
+                 ~~~
La palabra clave 'var' no se admite en esta versión del idioma.
En línea: 16 Carácter: 42
+                     beforeSend: function() {
+                                          ~
Se esperaba una expresión después de '('.
En línea: 33 Carácter: 56
+                             $('.message-warning').html(msg);
+                                                        ~
Falta el paréntesis de cierre ')' en la llamada al método.
En línea: 33 Carácter: 56
+                             $('.message-warning').html(msg);
+                                                        ~~~
Token 'msg' inesperado en la expresión o la instrucción.
En línea: 31 Carácter: 30
+                         else {
+                              ~
Falta la llave de cierre "}" en el bloque de instrucciones o la definición de tipo.
En línea: 21 Carácter: 44
+                                            ~
Falta la llave de cierre "}" en el bloque de instrucciones o la definición de tipo.
En línea: 11 Carácter: 24
+                 $.ajax({
+                        ~
Falta la llave de cierre "}" en el bloque de instrucciones o la definición de tipo.
En línea: 37 Carácter: 23
Falta una expresión después de ','.
No se notificaron todos los errores de análisis. Corrija los errores notificados e inténtelo de nuevo.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ReservedKeywordNotAllowed
 
             }
En línea: 1 Carácter: 13
+             }
+             ~
Token '}' inesperado en la expresión o la instrucción.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
 

        });
En línea: 1 Carácter: 9
+         });
+         ~
Token '}' inesperado en la expresión o la instrucción.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 10
+         });
+          ~
Token ')' inesperado en la expresión o la instrucción.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
 
    };
En línea: 1 Carácter: 5
+     };
+     ~
Token '}' inesperado en la expresión o la instrucción.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Comment: Los errores que compartes son warnings de PHP que realmente no causan el problema (aunque sería ideal solucionarlos porque las variables no están definidas correctamente). ¿Hay algún error en la consola de JavaScript?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Buenos dias, gracias por responder, te adjunto lo que me salta la consola al final de la consulta, por tema de caracteres.

Comment: Basándome en el mensjae de error de la consola, ¿has probado a cambiar `var` por `const`?

Answer (score 1):

JQuery está enviando la información del formulario *serilizada*, lo que la convierte en algo así:

```
"contactName=valor1&contactEmail=valor2&contactSubject=valor3" ... etc.
```

por ello no puedes asignar las variables de la forma en que lo haces, sino debes procesarlas primero, haciendo, por ejemplo:

```
$variables = [];   // o array(), si no puedes usar esta notación
parse_str($_GET, $variables);
```

Lo cual coloca tus variables en el array() llamado $variables.

Puedes ver ejemplos de uso de parse_str() en el manual de PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Comment: Gracias juan carlos! funciono, abrazo

Answer (score 0):

Logre solucionarlo con esto, gracias a todos!

JQuery está enviando la información del formulario serializada, lo que la convierte en algo así:

`contactName=valor1&contactEmail=valor2&contactSubject=valor3`... etc.
por ello no puedes asignar las variables de la forma en que lo haces, sino debes procesarlas primero, haciendo, por ejemplo:

```
$variables = [];   // o array(), si no puedes usar esta notación
parse_str($_GET, $variables);
```